# Dotfuscator Community Edition not working?

Tags: c#, dotfuscator

I used Dotfuscator Community Edition that comes with Visual Studio 2010 to obfuscate my Windows application. I used Redgate Obfuscation Checker on the executable and it showed the file as obfuscated and the methods and variables are renamed (although only to a limited extent). However when I checked the same executable using ILSpy, all the source code is intact. Nothing is changed. Can anyone suggest why it is so? 
Thanks.

Comment: Also you can use De4dot project to ensure that your assemblies are protected. De4dot is an open-source deobfucator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dotfuscator Community Edition does not support control flow obfuscation, which would make the code much more difficult/impossible to read in ILSpy. You must upgrade from Community Edition to use this feature.